# Adding geolocation to fragment google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have a MainActivity class, there in case of pressing botton navigation button this code works:

```
Fragment fragment = new MapFragment()
setContentView(R.layout.mapslaynav);
                        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
                        getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.framelay, fragment)
                                .commit();
```

This code replaces the *FrameLayout* and sets the *fragment* with GoogleMaps:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.locom.MapFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"

        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the class *MapFragment* that allows me to create markers on this google map

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
                getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {

                googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                        // Creating a marker
                        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                        // Setting the position for the marker
                        markerOptions.position(latLng);

                        // Setting the title for the marker.
                        // This will be displayed on taping the marker
                        markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + " : " + latLng.longitude);

                        // Clears the previously touched position
                        googleMap.clear();

                        // Animating to the touched position
                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

                        // Placing a marker on the touched position
                        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

My question is here: How will i get user's location and draw a point of it?

Comment: at first: read some doc about fetching location, [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates) and [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current). further: just add some marker in that point like you do in `onMapClick`

Comment: @snachmsm tried a lot on google tutorials, but all them need to add some code on `onClick` at activity that `extends AppCompatActivity and implements OnMapReadyCallback`, like [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/99fa07280b3658a59286881082fb2dce78d3a9c1/tutorials/java/CurrentPlaceDetailsOnMap/app/src/main/java/com/example/currentplacedetailsonmap/MapsActivityCurrentPlace.java). As you can see, my activity `extends Fragment`, so i don`t know, that to do.